# Apply image in bottom right corner

Tags: html

I need to apply a small image, a little badge, (bottom right) over some thumbnails of a gallery. The code is generate automatically by a plugin and looks like this. I can't change the order of the tags but I can edit the two lines marked with * (i.e. adding a classes, changing from span to div)
It works with top but not with bottom (top: 0px; right: 4px) don't know why.

```
<a href="/photos/fullpic.jpg">
<span>
*<span style="position: relative; display: block;">
     <img src="/photos/mythumbnail.jpg" alt="thumbnail">
    *<img src="/photos/plugins/badge.png" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; right: 4px;">
   </span>
</span>
```

edit: Forgot to add. Each thumbnail has different height/width so I can't declare an height for the container. It needs to stick bottom right regardless the dimension of the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me but you have to remove `display:block;` for the `<span>`

What is the "wrapper" `<span>` ?

Comment: Thanks. The <span> is randomly added by the plugin, I'm trying to get rid of it. Turns out I had a float:left added to another wrapper div (.wrapper img {float: left}) that was applied to the badge image too. This and display: block.

Answer (score 0):

one problem is the `display:block` as @MatTheCat mentioned, the other is the whitespace and text that is inside the span..

you should either wrap the text inside a span/div along with the badge and set that to be positioned relative. for the white space you can set the `font-size` and `line-height` to `0`.

example at http://jsfiddle.net/PEmEy/